# JS Testing: Sinon faking API response from other file?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, sinon, sinon-chai

My `MainCreator` file is running Sinon tests and I'm having an issue faking some calls when `makeIndents` is run.  It's loading in an external class, `HeaderCreator`, and calling the function `getHeaderCreds` from it which is making a real API call.
Is there a way in my `beforeEach` of `MainCreator` that I can resolve/fake that external file's function api call?

**MainCreator**

```
import { HeaderCreator } from './Headers.js';


export class MainCreator {
     
    ///

    makeIndents() {
         const foo = new HeaderCreator();
         
         foo.getHeaderCreds();
    }
}
```

**HeaderCreator**

```
export class HeaderCreator {

    getHeaderCreds() {
      // config values; 

      const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/v1/check`, config);
      const { results } = await response.json();
     
      return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you test the `makeIndents` method of the `MainCreator` class, since the `getHeaderCreds` of the `HeaderCreator` class is the direct dependency, you'd better stub it instead of the `fetch` function.

I will treat the `makeIndents` method as a unit for testing, not `makeIndents` and `getHeaderCreds`. This means I will only care about and test the code logic inside `makeIndents`. I don't care about the code logic inside `getHeaderCreds`. Since `getHeaderCreds` has a side effect(network I/O), so I stub it and its return value.

According to the above strategy, if you test the `getHeaderCreds` method, you should stub the `fetch` function and its return value.

E.g.

`Headers.ts`:

```
const baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000';
const config = {};
export class HeaderCreator {
  async getHeaderCreds() {
    const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/v1/check`, config);
    const { results } = await response.json();
    return results;
  }
}
```

`MainCreator.ts`:

```
import { HeaderCreator } from './Headers';

export class MainCreator {
  makeIndents() {
    const foo = new HeaderCreator();
    return foo.getHeaderCreds();
  }
}
```

`MainCreator.test.ts`:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { MainCreator } from './MainCreator';
import { HeaderCreator } from './Headers';

describe('72710555', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    sinon.stub(HeaderCreator.prototype, 'getHeaderCreds').resolves(['a', 'b']);
    const mainCreator = new MainCreator();
    const actual = await mainCreator.makeIndents();
    sinon.assert.match(actual, ['a', 'b']);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
  72710555
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (6ms)

----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File            | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files       |      70 |      100 |      50 |      70 |                   
 Headers.ts     |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 5-7               
 MainCreator.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```